# Why does my ../ in my include not work

Tags: php, centos

Why does my `../` in my include not work?

I want to go a folder back and enter a new folder but i get this warning:

> PHP Warning:  include(../folder/Information.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/bin/Code/TOOLS/main.php on line 1
>   PHP Warning:  include(): Failed opening '../folder/Information.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /home/user/bin/Code/TOOLS/main.php on line 1

Code:

```
<?PHP include "../folder/Information.php"; ?>
```

Folder structure:

```
home
-user
--bin
---Code
----TOOLS
-----main.php
----folder
-----Information.php
```

PHP v5.3 and higher. CentOS system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get your path working you should include the complete path in your include. You can achieve that by using a constant.

In earlier PHP-Version you have to use `dirname(__FILE__)`. In newer version you can use the constant `__DIR__`.

With both versions you get the absolute path to the file where you using that constant in. That path is with out the last slash. So you have to add them after the constant.

```
<?php include dirname(__FILE__)."/../folder/Information.php"; ?>
<?php include __DIR__."/../folder/Information.php"; ?>
```

with `../` you can change the directory one level higher and go the path back.

Answer (score 0):

Try including the **DIR** constant and/or a slash "/" before the "../"

```
<?PHP include __DIR__."/../folder/Information.php"; ?>
```

Comment: I have tryed to /../ but still the same result. and i do not want to use the __DIR__ constant

Comment: Why don't you want to use the DIR constant?

Comment: universal use. __DIR__ wil not work in lover versions and i don't want to if else every time

Comment: @vincentpoortvliet Seriously? Which version of PHP are you talking about that does not support `__DIR__`?

Comment: __dir__ is from 5.3.0 and higher see link: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

Try below code segment, I think this might work.
`<?PHP include "./folder/Information.php"; ?>`